# Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context .setRetryPolicy

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

Some kind guy gave me an answer to my question by posting code, however it isn't complete from the looks of it. I think its supposed to be a short timed-out kinda function, but it says "Non-static method setRetryPolicy (com.android.volley.RetryPolicy)' cannot be referenced from a static contex" 
I don't exactly know how to fix this myself, so I'd really appreciate if someone had a quick fix for this.
Here is the code;

```
RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username,password,isadmin,responseListener,errorListener);
                int socketTimeout = 500000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
                RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
                StringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
                // Creating RequestQueue.
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CreateUser.this);

                // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
                queue.add(registerRequest);
```

It gives that error at in the 4th line. This is also a continuation of my previous questions on trying to make a basic register script in Android Studio. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's meant to be

```
registerRequest.setRetryPolicy()
```

as that's the StringRequest instance in your code, and then one dealt with further down.

However, you really should just ask the person who posted the answer next time.